# Make use of ScaffoldMessenger in a GetX Controller

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to use something like the scaffoldMessenger in a GetX Controller?

I'd like to display a SnackBar via the scaffoldMessenger when a task is complete.

For example, I have a controller that uploads data to Firestore, and I'd like to show the SnackBar when this is complete:

```
  final ScaffoldMessengerState scaffoldMessenger = Get.find<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

  Future<void> startUpload(SaveGame saveGame) async {
    final UploadTask taskSnapshot = backupService.uploadFile(saveGame);

    await taskSnapshot
        .whenComplete(() =>
        scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text('Snack-tastic')),
        ));
  }
```

I tried wiring that into my `main.dart`

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ScaffoldMessengerState scaffoldMessenger =
        Get.put<ScaffoldMessengerState>(ScaffoldMessenger.of(context));

    return GetMaterialApp(...)
  }
}
```

But that just threw an exception

```
No ScaffoldMessenger widget found.
Typically, the ScaffoldMessenger widget is introduced by the MaterialApp at the top of your application widget tree.
```

I'm aware of the GetX GetBar and SnackBar alternative.

How would you typically solve this, would the pattern by to have my `startUpload` return and then in the 'screen/page' have the logic to display the snackbar where it has access to the `BuildContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap using the `Builder` to use the `context` of the `MaterialApp` like below.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GetMaterialApp(
    home: Builder(builder: (context) {
      Get.put<ScaffoldMessengerState>(ScaffoldMessenger.of(context));
      return const TestPage();
    }),
  );
}
```